# How can I check the password until it is correct?

Tags: c, loops, passwords, cs50

**I'm writing a program to read a password until it is correct. I'm confused about how to use the loop in this.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h> //cs library Harvard for getting input of string from the user
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{ 
    string first="hello"; 
    string check = get_string("Hello! \n, enter password ,"); //gets the string, input from the user.
    if (strcmp(first, check) == 0)
    { 
        printf("Welcome \n"); 
    } 
    else 
    {
        printf("\n wrong pwd, good bye \n");
    }//I want to put this part in loop until the correct pwd is entered.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem will be **solved using an infinite loop** that will run until the user enters the correct password.
So, for this task enclose your if-else statements and print inside the infinite while loop, which will break once a user gets the password right.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h> 
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{ 
  string first="hello"; 
  while(1)
  {
    string check = get_string("Hello! \n, enter password ,");
    if (strcmp(first, check) == 0)
    { 
      printf("Welcome \n"); 
      break;
    }
    else 
    {
      printf("\n wrong pwd, good bye \n");
    }
  }
}
```